# how to run a php code in widget?

Tags: php, widgets, sidebar, code

I have a code to get all taxonomies and terms for a single post:

```
$object_terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'staff', array('fields' => 'all'));
if ($object_terms) {
    echo '<p>' . '' . '' ;
    $res = '';
    foreach ($object_terms as $term) {
        $res .= '<a href="' . esc_attr(get_term_link($term, $taxonomy)) . '" title="' . sprintf(__("View artiles of: %s"), $term->name) . '" ' . '>' . $term->name . '</a>, ';
    }
    echo rtrim($res,' ,').' ' . '</p>';
}
```

the code works well when i put it in the single post php file. But when i try to put it in a widget using a special php code widget it shows nothing.
I tried other php codes in that widget and they run fine but this didn't.
Any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this with or without the return.

```
    $object_terms = wp_get_object_terms($GLOBALS['post']->ID, 'staff', array('fields' => 'all'));
    if ($object_terms) {
        echo '<p>' . '' . '' ;
        $res = '';
        foreach ($object_terms as $term) {
            $res .= '<a href="' . esc_attr(get_term_link($term, $taxonomy)) . '" title="' . sprintf(__("View artiles of: %s"), $term->name) . '" ' . '>' . $term->name . '</a>, ';
        }
        echo rtrim($res,' ,').' ' . '</p>';
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your response, actually i use a plugin to run php codes in widgets. all other codes are running fine but this didn't. does it really need a separate plugin?

Comment: I updated the answer try wrapping with ob_start(); ob_get_clean();

Comment: nothing happened :(

Comment: Are you sure you get results from the code within the post you are viewing ?  Add echo 1; echo 2;... after each line just to make sure that it is at least executing.

Comment: echo 1;
$object_terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'staff', array('fields' => 'all'));
echo 2;

Comment: within the post the code works perfectly it shows the terms that i need exactly. only when i try to run it in a widget it shows nothing. i can't figure out the reason and i really need this to work.

Comment: replace $post->ID  with  $GLOBALS['post']->ID

Comment: still giving nothing :(

Comment: Can you get anything to display like a simple echo 1; and nothing else ?

Comment: no no no it worked!!!!!! but i had to delete     ob_start(); and     return ob_get_clean();  thaaaaaaaaaaaaanks a lot please edit your code to give you a thanks mark